# How to unconditionally toggle parent checkbox

Tags: org-mode

In the following example Org mode buffer, I cannot check the `Parent` checkbox without first checking the `Child` checkbox:

```
- [ ] Parent
  - [ ] Child
```

Is there some way to loosen this restriction?  There is a user option called `org-enforce-todo-dependencies` that bypasses such dependency-checking for `TODO` entries, but I cannot find such an option for checkboxes.

I'm using version 9.1.14 of `org.el`.

Answer (score 2):

You can literally write an X into the box.  It's just text!  You could give that scene some meaning and take care.

AFAICS Org is quite rigid to only allow the transition to [X] via `C-c C-c` or `C-c C-x C-b` when all the children are already in state [X].

To set [X] to a bunch of items, e.g. in the whole subtree of plain items below the item you want to [X], you could define a region around that items before the `C-c C-c`.

Comment: +1 for `It's just text!`.

Comment: Just typing an X is a decent workaround, and it's what I've been doing. The thing is, I've grown accustomed to using the mouse to check my checkboxes and dropping down to the level of raw text editing causes a minor disruption to my workflow. I do appreciate your response, however.